# How can I validate a DMG file?

Tags: macos, dmg

I have an application that builds into a DMG file (via [jpackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/jpackage/packaging-overview.html#GUID-C1027043-587D-418D-8188-EF8F44A4C06A)).
As soon as users download the DMG they tell me it is corrupt and should be deleted.

Now I am unfamiliar with that format and I have no access to any Apple Mac to try myself. Just in case jpackage is really building an invalid package I would like to check that before offering such a download.

Is there any way to validate a DMG on Github's MacOS runner?

Comment: "corrupt and should be deleted" sounds like a code signing problem. Knowing the exact error message would help clarify this. Also, do the users get that error when mounting the DMG, when running the program, or what?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about the exact message or cause. These users are nontechnical enough, hence asking for validation that I can perform.

Comment: I doubt there's any automated validation tool that'd check this sort of thing reliably. I think you have to approach this as something that needs to be debugged, and that's pretty much going to involve running it on a Mac (or having remote access to a user's Mac, or something like that).

Comment: At whoever believes this is not a programming question: The dialog lists "Use this close reason if the question is not about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers." Packagers to distribute an application are for sure programming tools. So why should not a verification tool be part of it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this web page https://macwrench.miraheze.org/wiki/Hdiutil which mentions that `hdiutil` supports a number of commands that are useful for validating a DMG file:

```
hdiutil verify -verbose <dmg>
hdiutil imageinfo -verbose <dmg>
hdiutil hfsanalyze -verbose <dmg>
hdiutil checksum -type SHA256 -verbose <dmg>
hdiutil info -verbose
hdiutil pmap -verbose <dmg>
```

The first one already gave me output that ended like this:

```
hdiutil: verify: checksum of "<dmg>" is VALID
verified   CRC32 $9D7EB279
```

So with this I can trust my generated file and should look for issues on the download or user side.